# Passing a directory in bash trough pipe communication

Tags: bash, unix, pipe

This problem is a homework, I know there would be much easier ways of solving this problem, but it is what it is.

The question goes as follows:
  -I have a bash script that does some creates some files.
  -I have to pass this first argument of this script ( which is a directory ) to another script trough a pipeline ( `|` ).

The problem comes in when I do try and pass this directory as an argument, in the other script, the argument I receive is `null`.

This is the whole code, in this exact order.
Nothing was left out.

The first script receives at least 11 argument:

```
if [[ $# -lt 11 ]]; then
    echo "Not enough arguments." >&2;
    exit 1;
fi;
```

The script will check if the first argument is an actual directory:

```
if [[ ! -d $1 ]]; then
    echo "Not a valid first argument." >&2;
    exit 1;
fi;
```

Here, I'll save my first directory here so that I can `shift`, and then I'm going to declare more stuff that i need

```
Directory=$1;
shift;
N=$#
name_array=("$#")
Pos=0;
```

Afterwards, the script will use all the other arguments to create .txt files with those names, and add a number of non-null lines in each .txt file ( So, argument2.txt has N-1 lines, argument3.txt has N-2 lines ... argumentN.txt has 1 line.) Afterwards, I have to change their permissions to 600.

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    if [[ -a "$Directory"/"$1".txt ]]; then
        rm "$Directory"/"$1".txt;
    fi
        touch "$Directory"/"$1".txt
        for((i=0;i<N;i++)); do
            echo "$N" >> "$Directory"/"$1".txt;
        done;
        chmod u=rw "$Directory"/"$1".txt;
        N=$(($N-1));
        name_array["$Pos"]="$Directory"/"$1".txt;
        Pos=$(($Pos + 1));
        shift;
done;
```

Problem comes here, I'm trying to `echo` the first directory..

```
echo $Directory;
```

I have tried this as well, with the same results as the one above

```
echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$Directory")" && pwd -P)/$(basename "$Directory")";
```

.. like this so I can use in the Shell the pipeline commands.

The second script will receive the directory, enter it and search trough all the files that have been created just now.

In the Unix terminal, I use this:

```
./FirstScript.bash 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 | ./SecondScript.bash
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using a pipe means the recipient should read standard input instead of process command-line arguments. But it's really not clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: yes, you've left out the most important part of your problem. The rest of this could have been reduced to `FirstScript ${Dir} x x | ./SecondScript`. AND it's not clear what advantage is offered by `echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$Directory")" && pwd -P)/$(basename "$Directory")";`. Just stick with `echo "$Directory"` (what will your current code do if your instructor starts it with `FirstScript "Dir With Spaces" x x `? ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I was asked to give the absolute path do the next script trough pipeline connection, sorry for not being clear about that. And yes, i am now sticking with ```echo $SomeArgument | ./SomeScript.bash ``` for the sake of all that's holy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for being honest, and of course we're not going to do your homework, but,...

Most of the code seems pretty good. There are some smaller issues, which you might easily solve with `shellcheck` (if it isn't installed, install it or use the web version), and I would not put `;` at the end of each line.

So, instead of running the complete pipeline at once, break it down to find where your problem lies. If you run

```
./FirstScript.bash 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

If the output is as expected (so, with the `echo $Directory`), and the files are created, then the first script is good. So, in this case, the directory `1` will contain the files `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`, and the output will be `1`.

Then, you will run the second script

```
 ./SecondScript.bash
```

and as input you will give:

```
1
^D
```

(that is control-d on Unix). And then the second script should do what you want (or not).

In this way you can debug the scripts separately.

(quick face-palm question: is 1 really the directory you want, or did you just forget the directory name as first argument?)

Comment: It was just a quick example. I am not gonna name my directories as 1. Either way, i have managed to solve my problem. I documented myself more when it comes to pipelines and i realized how to actually use them properly. Either way, thanks for the response!

Comment: And another quick question. When someone says that they want a pipeline connection between two scripts, is it considered wrong to have, at the end of the first script, let's say ```echo $SomeArgument | ./SecondScript.bash```? I believe it still is a pipeline connection between 2 scripts, but then again, I might be wrong in this.